# Is the reading of 棚主【たなぬし】 or perhaps 棚主【ほうしゅ】?

Tags: readings, neologism

> シェア型【がた】本屋【ほんや】では、棚主【たなぬし】は自分【じぶん】で本を持【も】ってこないといけないし、店番【みせばん】だってある([source](https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPD45RT6PCVUTIL023.html?iref=comtop_Culture_04))
> *In a shared bookstore, the shelf owners have to bring their own books, and they also have to guard the store.*

The idea of a "shelf owner" is a concept too new for dictionaries, apparently.

Comment: It may have been coined as a pun on the existing word [店主]{たなぬし}. Instead of the whole shop, they own only a few shelves in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most people would read this as たなぬし using the kun-reading. The biggest reason is simply because the on-reading of 棚 is little-known.

I also feel たなしゅ is unlikely. Among the words that end with 主 meaning *owner*, there are kun-kun compounds (宿主【やどぬし】, 生主【なまぬし】, 家主【やぬし】), on-kun compounds (馬主【ばぬし】), and on-on compounds (店主【てんしゅ】, 社主【しゃしゅ】), but I cannot think of kun-on ones.

Comment: 「喪主」って、訓＋音なんだって～！へ～ 珍しいよね～

Comment: @Chocolate おお気づかなかった…